# snort threshold.conf

Tags: signature, snort

I have suppressed a certain signature in etc/snort/threshold.conf, but after I saved and came out from threshold.conf file, I am still seeing those alerts in log file, here my question is do I need to restart my snort or automatically the changes will take place, this is what I hev tried I am testing snort I have written this signature "alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"this is for testing";sid:100000111;rev:2;)" . This signature ID I suppresses in /etc/snort/treshold.conf like this,`suppress gen_id 1, sig_id 100000111`and on console I am still seeing the alerts displaying with the message ***[]this is for testing[]****

Comment: What alerts? What log file? What do you mean by "suppressed a certain signature"? How did you do that? What exactly did you change in `/etc/snort/threshold.conf`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I am testing snort I have written this signature "alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"this is for testing";sid:100000111;rev:2;)" . This signature ID I suppresses in /etc/snort/treshold.conf  like this, suppress gen_id, sig_id 100000111

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and add these details.

Comment: And when I am running snort on my console I am seeing still these alerts on console 12/12-15:13:12.243 [**] [xxx] this is for testing[] bla bla....., do I need to restart snort to take these changes or any way is there without distrubing the running snort we can comment out rules which are not intersted.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify. Use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format your post and explain what you edited where. I don't understand what you added to the threshld.conf file and what you are trying to suppress.